# docusignapi Add document binary

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to add a document to envelope. However I have that document in a blob column in the Oracle database. I tried to load that in the blob variable, convert to clob (using blob2clob oracle function) and send the information. however, I always get the document empty on docusign. So, I was thinking a way to send the information in binary form.

Does somebode know the correct setup to sent taht or any help with this?

Thank you, 
Jose

Answer (score 0):

Give [this thread](http://community.docusign.com/t5/Misc-Dev-Archive-READ-ONLY/Error-quot-Content-Type-for-part-0-must-be-application-json-or/td-p/11483) on the DocuSign community a look and see if it will resolve your issue